# Tomcat 7 monitoring with e-mail notifications

Tags: tomcat7, monitoring

I've been looking for a bit but can't find a free/open-source tomcat 7 monitoring tool that will send out e-mails or notifications when certain situations occur. For example when CPU utilization spikes or RAM is consistently full. Things Like that.

I've looked at JMelody and Psi-Probe and neither of them have the ability to send e-mails when some event occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [jboss RHQ](http://www.jboss.org/rhq)

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/RHQ/Alerts

Comment: This looks like exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone!!

If one do not want to use any monitoring tool, then set up an email configurtion in Ubuntu server using mailutils package.

https://rianjs.net/2013/08/send-email-from-linux-server-using-gmail-and-ubuntu-two-factor-authentication

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

To monitor Tomcat status you can use below script and set up cron job which runs every minute/hour/day according to your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/tomcat
PUBLIC_IP=`wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q ; echo`
EMAIL_BODY="Hi Admin,\n\n$PUBLIC_IP Tomcat is down at $(date -d "+330 minutes" +"%Y-%m-%d %T") IST, Please take necessary action.\n\n\nDo not reply to this email as it is auto generated by Ubuntu system\n"

tomcat_pid() {
  echo `ps aux | grep org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
}

start() {
  pid=$(tomcat_pid)
  if [ -n "$pid" ] 
  then
    echo "Tomcat is already running (pid: $pid)"
  else
    # Start tomcat
    echo "Starting tomcat"
    /bin/sh $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh
  fi


  return 0
}

pid=$(tomcat_pid)

 if [ -n "$pid" ]
  then
    echo "Tomcat is running with pid: $pid"
    #stop
  else
    echo "Tomcat is not running"
    # send an email alert then start
    echo -e $EMAIL_BODY | mail -s "$PUBLIC_IP Tomcat is down" user@email.com
    echo "Mail sent"
    #remove cache and release memory occupied by heavy processes
    start
  fi
exit 0
```